# Match Cell Data Based on Cell Value and Iterate Down Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet ("Sheet D") with different column headings than ("Sheet A") except for column A which is a part numbers column. I need to be able to go to ("Sheet D") and iterate down each row column A for the part number and find the matching part number in ("Sheet A") column A. If the part number from ("Sheet D") is found in ("Sheet A"), I need to copy the entire row where it was found and paste it into ("Sheet D") starting in column K. If the part number is not found in ("Sheet A"), I want it to skip that row in ("Sheet D") and leave it blank and move to the row below it and repeat. So far, I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
Sub Excel()

Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
PN As Range
PNRow As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet A").Columns("A")
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 2 To N
              For j = 2 To N
                    Set PN = .Find(Worksheets("Sheet D").Cells(i, "A").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    If PN Is Nothing Then
                            GoTo NextIteration
                    Else
                    PNRow = PN.Row
                    Range(Sheets("Sheet A").Cells(PNRow, 1), Sheets("Sheet A").Cells(PNRow, 10)).Copy Range(j, "K")
                    End If
NextIteration:
               Next j
        Next i

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Update_Data()

    Dim d As Worksheet: Set d = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet D")
    Dim a As Worksheet: Set a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet A")
    
    ' **IMPORTANT** header row locations
    Dim d_headerRow As Integer: d_headerRow = 1
    Dim a_headerRow As Integer: a_headerRow = 1
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer, part As String
    Dim d_lastRow As Long: d_lastRow = d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim a_lastRow As Long: a_lastRow = a.Cells(a.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim a_lastCol As Integer: a_lastCol = a.Cells(a_headerRow, a.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For i = d_headerRow + 1 To d_lastRow
        part = d.Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        For j = a_headerRow + 1 To a_lastRow
            If part = a.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                a.Range(a.Cells(j, 1), a.Cells(j, a_lastCol)).Copy Destination:=d.Range(d.Cells(i, 11), d.Cells(i, 11))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this taking the first instance of when the part number appears each time? The code works but "Sheet A" has the part number appear more than once. I'll need it to skip the one it already pasted and find the rest of the rows they appear in as well to paste into "Sheet D"

Comment: If you want to keep all instances, remove the "Exit For".